# Bootstrap select picker is not working in iphone 6

Tags: iphone, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap 3 select picker is not working on iphone 6. My code is bellow

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
    style: 'btn-default',
    size: false
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.myselectpicker').selectpicker('mobile');
});
```